# How to finish() other activities (if they are open)

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application I have 2 activities (A and B) and 1 service.

Each activity can call the other finishing itself.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
finish();
startActivity(i);
```

The application can create a status bar icon, clicking status bar an intent open activity A using flag

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Moreover I have an exit button that kill activity and service.

My problem if I have Activity B open and the user clicks status bar icon, because user now see activity A, but if he clicks exit button the application close activity A and service but show the underground Activity B. How can I solve the problem closing also Activity B

**Edit:**

I solve with a SharedPreferences value that I set to false at application starting and to true at exit button click. In onResume() I check the value and finish the activity if it is true.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following: Change the intent from the statusbar to

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("com.help.KILLME");
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

and then put this in the Activity you want to close from the statusbar:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        finish();
    }
};


//OnCreate method
//[...]
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.help.KILLME");
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

This would stop the active Activity (don't forget to unregister the Receiver in `onPause()` and reregister it in `onResume()` )